# Zoom/scale feature on image when hovering, hovered image will not be "on top". Can I use CSS?

Tags: html, css, gallery, scale

So I have a question... Hi and thank you for reading:

I'm using "Responsive Flickr Gallery", or "RFG" in wordpress, and I'm trying to achieve a zoom/scale on hover image.

As in: When you hover over a image in the gallery, said image will scale x2 times and I'm using this:

```
img.rfg-img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

This totally works.

However: It's as if each image is on an own layer. When I hover over image 1, it's "beneath" the other images.

When I hover over image 18, however, it's "above" every other images. I want all of the pictures to act image 18 (last picture on page 1).

I'm guessing you have to make a div appear on top of another or something, somehow, and I have no idea how to do that.

Can I use CSS to do this? Is it even possible?

Here's a link:

http://beautifiedbyelsa.se/wordpress/galleri1/

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Comment: please create a fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Alejelapeno fixed it perfectly:)

Answer (score 0):

Elements further down the DOM appear in front of elements higher up the DOM. `z-index` alters this natural hierarchy. In order for the element to be altered by the property it needs to have a `position` of relative, absolute, fixed or sticky. (Otherwise known as a 'positioned element')

```
img.rfg-img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(2);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much for your help. Greatly appreciated! PS. I tried using position without any success, i guess I was missing the z-index bit of code. Thank you again. :)

Comment: @Advokaten Great, make sure to mark as answer for future readers.